# task fstrim blocked for more than 120 seconds

Tags: linux, lvm, ssd, linux-kernel, ubuntu-14.04

I'm experiencing random crashes on my system.

I've narrowed the problem to the fstrim program that's launched weekly by cron.

In the console, I've got a set of blocked tasks among whigetch I find fstrim. (other blocked tasks are jdb2/dm, rs:main Q:Reg, kworker/u16).

I tried running fstrim manually and reproduced the crash, but can't get more details than the blocked tasks messages - all is frozen.

Any idea on how I can find out what happens?

My setup is:
1 SSD containing 2 LVM2 partitions
1 HDD with 2 LVM2 partitions which are the mirrors of the SSD ones.

Any obvious mistake with that setup?

My system is Ubuntu 14.04 64bit, kernel 3.13.0-35-generic.
issue_discards is enabled in lvm.conf

Comment: I think it's relevant to add that the SSD is a Sandisk (SDSSDP064G).

Comment: fstrim working on a NTFS partition seems to be incredibly slow. It entirely blocks access to the affected partition and can take over 14 hours to complete for just 50GB. Only solution atm: don't use or trim NTFS. Avoid NTFS at all cost.